# Synchronous pdf generation through pdfmonkey

Tags: pdf-generation

I am using pdfMonkey to store PDF template and generate PDF, I am calling pdfMonkey API mentioned in below link for generating pdf. I am getting success response but download_url is coming as null and preview_url is also returning 400. In order to fetch the PDF download url, I have to call get document API. So I have to do couple of API calls to generating a PDF. Is there any way I can generate PDF in single API call?

https://docs.pdfmonkey.io/references/api/documents#generating-the-document-upon-creation

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: No, I have the response from pdfMonkey that this will most probably never happen. Awaiting the generation before answering your request would mean keeping a connection open until we respond. There's a limited amount of connections a server can keep open at the same time. That's what is called a Denial-of-Service (DoS) and that's something that we want to avoid at all costs. All of this is why the PDF generation is asynchronous as it takes a variable amount of time to complete.